# AngularStrap: data-template-url not render in tooltip

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-strap

I use angular strap in my project.

I want use tooltip, and render a template by 'data-template-url'. For this, I do this:

`dependencies`:

```
'mgcrea.ngStrap',
'mgcrea.ngStrap.tooltip',
```

`controllerCtrl.coffee:`

```
$scope.tooltip = {
   "title": "Hello Tooltip<br />This is a multiline message!"
};
```

in `html`:

```
<a href data-animation="am-flip-x" data-template-url="assets/templates/messageTooltip.html" bs-tooltip>you probably</a>
```

and `messageTooltip.html`:

```
<div class="tooltip in" ng-show="title">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner" ng-bind="content">
        <p>test tooltip</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

but when I run project, no sction is accured.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Plunker with a working tooltip template:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jFntZyFw3W9QfTQBlFr4?p=preview

The template is:

```
<div class="tooltip in" ng-show="title">
  <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
  <div class="tooltip-title" ng-bind="title"></div>
  <div class="tooltip-inner" ng-bind="txtcontent"></div>
</div>
```

and in CSS I have defined `tooltip-title` class similar to Bootstrap `tooltip-inner` class:

```
.tooltip-title {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```